# How to minimize a list of data points?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a list called diff1:

```
axis = Table[i, {i, 1, 20}];
data1 = Table[Sin[i/(2*Pi)], {i, 1, 20}];
model1[t_] := a*Sin[b*t];
model1points = Map[model1, axis];
diff1 = (model1points - data1)^2;
```

One example of the entry of diff1:
     (a Sin[3 b] - Sin[3/(2*Pi)])^2
I want to minimize the elements of this list with respect to `a` and `b`. How can I do that?

Comment: Check documentation for `Fit`or maybe `NonlinearFit`.

Comment: You probably want to minimize the their `Sum[]`

Comment: `NMinimize[Total@diff1, {a, b}]` or, to minimize each element of the list,  `NMinimize[#, {a, b}] & /@ diff1`?

Comment: @kguler. Yes, I should minimize their sum. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{min, argmin} = NMinimize[Total@diff1, {a, b}];
(* {0., {a -> 1., b -> 0.159155}}  -- as expected since N[1/(2*Pi)] is 0.159155  *)
{ahat, bhat} = argmin[[All,2]];
(* {1., 0.159155} *)
pred = Table[ahat Sin[i bhat], {i, 1, 20}];
ListPlot[{data1, pred}, Joined -> {False, True}]
```

[image]